# Can I apply a condition globally using automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

Simple question but cant seem to find the answer.  Can I apply `.ForAllMembers(options => options.Condition(c => !c.IsSourceValueNull));` globally in the configuration so I dont have to apply it to all of my objects?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you figured it out?

Comment: Your question may be duplicated with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822882/how-to-configure-conditional-mapping-in-automapper

Answer (score 0):

Create a global mapper configuration:

```
new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    Func<object, object, object, bool> condition = (src, dest, sourceMember) => sourceMember != null;
    cfg.ForAllMaps(((map, expression) => expression.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(condition))));
});
```

Tested with Automapper 9.