# automapper conditional Custom Value Resolver

Tags: c#, automapper

Is it possible to use a custom value resolver in automapper only if a certain condition is met?

In my case I only want to update the value with the custom value resolver if the **destination** is not null.

This is an example of my code. Basically I need to add the condition onto this. Is it possible?

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ResponseXml, MyModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, 
                 op => op.ResolveUsing<ResponseXmlValueResolver>()
                .FromMember(x => x.data.FirstOrDefault(y => y.name == "name")))
```

Comment: would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822882/how-to-configure-conditional-mapping-in-automapper

Comment: no - I'm using a custom value resolver and they're not

Answer (score 1):

I think Eris' solution would have work; It was just grammatical errors.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ResponseXml, MyModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, 
             op => {
                    op.Condition(src => src != null);
                    op.ResolveUsing<ResponseXmlValueResolver>();
                      .FromMember(x => x.data.FirstOrDefault(y => y.name == "name"));
             });
```

Is this what you wanted? 
If the destination is null, the mapping will be ignore.
If the destination is null, the mapping (with the customer resolved) will be apply.

Comment: This is not correct because conditions are evaluated *AFTER* resolving value as stated here https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Resolvers-and-conditions

Answer (score 0):

As Conditions are evaluated **after** resolving member, like it's said [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Resolvers-and-conditions), none of the previous answers are correct.
You should rather use PreCondition this way:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ResponseXml, MyModel>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, 
         op => {
                op.PreCondition(src => src != null);
                op.ResolveUsing<ResponseXmlValueResolver>();
                  .FromMember(x => x.data.FirstOrDefault(y => y.name == "name"));
         });
```

Answer (score -1):

Will this work? (I don't have a windows box in front of me at the moment)

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ResponseXml, MyModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, 
             op => op.Condition(src => src != null)
                     .ResolveUsing<ResponseXmlValueResolver>()
                     .FromMember(x => x.data.FirstOrDefault(y => y.name == "name")))
```